# Wait for Navigator.pop() to finish job

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, animation, flutter, routes

I have a search dialog, which displays list of found items.
When user clicks an item, I want to pop search dialog then read and display data, but read is a heavy task.

**(Navigator.pop() is sync and is not a Future)**

If my code is something like this :

```
Navigator.pop(context);
readSelectedItem();
```

This will slow down transition animation and makes view laggy.

I should do something like this, which is of course dirty code:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
readSelectedItem();
```

Comment: if it is a *"a heavy task"* then use an `Isolate` - most likely by calling `compute()` top level function

Comment: and what do you really mean by *"heavy task"*? is it something that really blocks the CPU or just some long running **async** code?

Comment: just long running async code, maybe 2 seconds